# pine script error undeclared identifier loop

Tags: loops, variables, tuples, tradingview-api

im getting this error, even though these were declared earlier as a tuple (var float[] bullFVGMinZones = array.new_float(0)):

errors are:  Undeclared identifier 'bullFVGMinZones', Undeclared identifier 'startIndex',
The end value of the "for" loop must be a number.

for this function:

```
comparePreviousCandleToFVGZones() =>
    [bullFVGMinZones, bullFVGMaxZones, bearFVGMinZones, bearFVGMaxZones] = collectFVGZones()

var aboveFVG = false
var belowFVG = false
var bullFVGMinLimit = math.min(array.size(bullFVGMinZones), 1000)
var startIndex = array.size(bullFVGMinZones) - bullFVGMinLimit
var bearFVGMinLimit = math.min(array.size(bearFVGMinZones), 1000)
var startIndex2 = array.size(bearFVGMinZones) - bearFVGMinLimit
// Check if bullFVGMinZones has elements before accessing index 0
// Initialize variables



if array.size(bullFVGMinZones) > 1
for i = startIndex to array.size(bullFVGMinZones) - 1
    if close[i] > array.get(bullFVGMinZones, i)
        aboveFVG := true
        break
// Check if bearFVGMinZones has elements before accessing index 0
```

if array.size(bearFVGMinZones) > 1

```
for i = startIndex2 to array.size(bearFVGMinZones) - 1
    if close[1] < array.get(bearFVGMinZones, i)
        belowFVG := true
        break

[aboveFVG, belowFVG]
```

ANY HELP WOULD BE MUCH APRECIATED THANKS!

Tried to declare variables  but didnt help